# How to send an existing message in a new email without losing formatting

Tags: python, email, gmail-api, mime-types

**Context:**
I'm attempting to send an existing email in my inbox to a new thread.

**Problem:**
I've successfully sent the email body using [this function](https://gist.github.com/miohtama/5389146) however the body loses the formatting of the original email and only sends text.

I think it makes more sense to add the entire payload to the request body, as documented on the [gmail API page](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send) "Try this API" section:

[image]

However when I add payload to the request body:

```
def create_message(sender, to, subject, thread_id, message_id, payload, service):
  """Create a message for an email.

  Args:
    sender: Email address of the sender.
    to: Email address of the receiver.
    subject: The subject of the email message.
    message_text: The text of the email message.

  Returns:
    An object containing a base64url encoded email object.
  """

  message = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
  message['to'] = to
  message['from'] = sender
  message['subject'] = 'Re: %s' %subject

  return {'raw': raw, 'threadId': thread_id, 'payload': payload}
```

The emails are sent with no content. How can I add an existing email to a new thread without having to decode and encode and lose the email's formatting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After messing around I've made two functions that can pass the `plain` and `html` content types to a new email for anyone else who might be struggling:

```
def get_all_parts(service, user_id, msg_id):
  message = service.users().messages().get(userId=user_id, id=msg_id, format='raw').execute()
  msg_bytes = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(message['raw'].encode('ASCII'))
  b = email.message_from_bytes(msg_bytes)
  body = []

  if b.is_multipart():
    for part in b.walk():
      if part.get_content_maintype() != 'multipart':
        this_part = []
        this_part.append(part.get_payload(decode=True))
        this_part.append(part.get_content_type())
        body.append(this_part)

  return body

def create_message(sender, to, subject, thread_id, message_id, message_text, service):
  message = MIMEMultipart()
  message['to'] = to
  message['from'] = sender
  message['subject'] = 'Re: %s' %subject
  for part in message_text:
    text = part[1].split('/') # 'text/plain' -> ['text', 'plain']
    new_part = MIMEText(str(part[0]), text[1])
    print(part[1])
    message.attach(new_part)

  raw = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_string().encode('UTF-8')).decode('ascii')   
  body = {'raw': raw, 'threadId': thread_id}

enter code here
```

This is definitely not an exhaustive function for all emails but works for `alternative` content types.

Answer (score 0):

If you open an email from Gmail UI, click on the three dots and chose "Show original",

you can observe the email structure

**Sample:**

> Message

[image]

> Show original

[image]

- You can see that the message is `multipart/alternative` and contains a `text/plain` and a `text/html` part
- If you use the whole highlighted code in the sample as the body of your message, the formatting will be preserved. You only need to specify the `From`, `To` and `Subject` headers.

Comment: You haven't specified how to add the highlighted code to the body programmatically using the gmail API.